# VB.NET How To Reverse ProgressBar

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, countdown

So I created a ProgressBar, BackgroundWorker, Timer and a Label that counts Total Files inside a folder. I want to go from 0% to 100% based on the amount of Files Remaining. My problem is that it starts out at 100% and counts down to 0% as it deletes the files and counts down to 0 because Files Remaining is set as Max value for ProgressBar. Is there a simple way to make it start at 0% and increase to 100% as the Label counts down to 0? Below is code:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Dim I = labelFileCount.Text
    '  labelFileCount.Text = I 'report to label
    BackgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(I) 'report
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.ProgressChanged
    MetroProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub CountFiles(InFolder As String, ByRef Result As Integer)
    Result += IO.Directory.GetFiles(InFolder).Count
    For Each f As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(InFolder)
        CountFiles(f, Result)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CountFilesTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CountFilesTimer.Tick
    Dim orderFolder As String
    orderFolder = My.Settings.Path & "\" & MetroTextBox1.Text
    Dim FileCount As Integer = 0
    CountFiles(orderFolder, FileCount)
    labelFileCount.Text = FileCount.ToString
End Sub

   Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    Dim orderFolder As String
    orderFolder = My.Settings.AgencyDataPath & "\" & MetroTextBox1.Text
    MsgBox(orderFolder)
    Dim FileCount As Integer = 0
    CountFiles(orderFolder, FileCount)
    MessageBox.Show(FileCount.ToString)
    labelFileCount = FileCount.ToString
    MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = Label1.Text
    CountFilesTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `MetroProgressBar1.Value = 100 - e.ProgressPercentage` ?

Comment: This starts it off at 2% rather than 100% but the progressBar doesn't change regardless of files remaining count while deleting and even after deleting.

Comment: What's the difference between `My.Settings.AgencyDataPath` and `My.Settings.Path` ?

Comment: They are the exact same. I just removed 'Agency' from code before I put it online here.

Comment: It now starts at 0% after adding MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = Label1.Text to Button6.Click but throws an exception in mscorlib.dll so I haven't been able to test if it goes up yet. Still working on it.

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

When calling:    BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()

Comment: Fixed all errors but still doesn't move from 0%. If I change it back to original, it will countdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since additional information from the OP has come to light, and since the OP asked for suggestions on their posted answer code, I offer the following.  Timer not necessary, Imports reduced and commented as to why, code simplified.

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem

' Do not import System.IO to ensure avoidance of namespace conflict / confusion
' Specify IO. in the code where it's needed for IO.SearchOptions (2 places)
' Any File / Directory methods called below are Alphaleonis unless IO is specified

Public Class Form1
    Private FilesList As List(Of String)
    Private orderFolder As String = String.Empty

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        orderFolder = Path.Combine(My.Settings.AgencyDataPath, MetroTextBox1.Text)

        Button1.Enabled = False
        ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Started Deleting: " & orderFolder)

        ' Capture list of all files in all subfolders
        FilesList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(orderFolder, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories, PathFormat.LongFullPath).ToList

        ' Initialize Label1 with FileCount
        Label1.Text = FilesList.Count.ToString

        ' Initialize ProgressBar
        MetroProgressBar1.Value = 0
        MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = FilesList.Count

        ' Execute DeleteFiles in separate thread
        Task.Run(Sub() DeleteFiles())
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteFiles()
        ' Delete all files in all folders
        For Each Filename As String In FilesList
            File.Delete(Filename, False, PathFormat.LongFullPath)
            UpdateProgress()
        Next

        ' Remove the now empty folder structure
        Directory.Delete(orderFolder, True)

        FinishProgress()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateProgress()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() UpdateProgress())
        Else
            MetroProgressBar1.Value += 1
            MetroProgressBar1.Refresh()

            Label1.Text = (FilesList.Count - MetroProgressBar1.Value).ToString
            Label1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FinishProgress()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() FinishProgress())
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Finished Deleting: " & orderFolder)
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this when I can tonight. I would give you rep but I don't have enough yet. I'll be back for ya though!

Comment: [link](http://pasteboard.co/vyP6Vl51y.png) - Files Remaining goes into negatives. I'll look around but let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks again! [screenshot](http://pasteboard.co/vyP6Vl51y.png)

Comment: I was able to fix this by changing Label1.Text = (FilesList.Count - MetroProgressBar1.Value).ToString TO  Label1.Text = FilesList.Count.ToString in the updateProgress function.

Comment: @FireStarter I hope you see this.  Restore `Label1.Text = (FilesList.Count - MetroProgressBar1.Value).ToString`, change FilesList declaration to `Private FilesList As List(Of String)` and add `.ToList` to the end of the line `FilesList = Directory.EnumerateFiles ....` as I've done above. The `for-each` against the IEnumerable was having it rescan the folder every iteration which is why you got negatives and its miserably slow. By caching to a List, it only does it once, the countdown is correct, and it's MUCH faster.

Comment: Works like a charm and so much faster! Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and faster approach.  No need of a timer, or repeatedly counting files recursively by folder. `Task.Run` puts the work in a background thread, which needs the `Me.Invoke` mechanism to update the UI properly.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private FilesList As List(Of String)

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Button6.Enabled = False

        ' Capture list of all files in all subfolders
        FilesList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(My.Settings.Path, MetroTextBox1.Text), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList

        ' Initialize ProgressBar
        MetroProgressBar1.Value = 0
        MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = FilesList.Count

        ' Execute DeleteFiles in separate thread
        Task.Run(Sub() DeleteFiles())
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteFiles()
        For Each Filename As String In FilesList
            File.Delete(Filename)
            UpdateProgress()
        Next

        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() Button6.Enabled = True)
        Else
            Button6.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateProgress()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() UpdateProgress())
        Else
            MetroProgressBar1.Value += 1
            MetroProgressBar1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

References:

- [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [InvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This DOES work but only deletes the files and not the folders/sub-folders and also doesn't delete files with super-large filenames which is why I am using the AlphaFS Filesystem. I am going to fiddle with your code to see if I can make it work with AlphaFS. If so, then this is definitely the answer! I may need your help with making it work with AlphaFS though because I haven't messed with VB since my AOL proggin days in the 90s hehe. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what your delete logic is, but if you're getting rid of all, then wouldn't you want to just delete the parent folder in one call? `Directory.Delete(path, true)` for example. You get no progress, though.

Comment: The progress bar isn't required. I really just wanted to learn progress bars and I figured why not add it to my delete tool along with a label that displays files remaining. I have figured it out and will post code as an answer and mark yours as correct but feel free to let me know if you have any suggestions on my revised code of yours.

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look. Your original question didn't specify deleting folders, long names, or AlphaFS. I'd have made a better answer in that case :)

Comment: Answer posted and also marked yours as correct since it helped me get there :)

Answer (score 0):

MrGadget got me going in the right direction but it but only deletes the files and not the folders/sub-folders and it also doesn't delete files with super-large filenames which is why I am using the AlphaFS Filesystem. Here is MrGadgets revised code which I have added a Timer and Label. Label1 = FilesCount so when it hits 0, the timer will call to delete the root folder and all sub-folders.

[click here for image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc3tD.png)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Alphaleonis
Imports Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1    
Private FilesList As IEnumerable(Of String)

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Enabled = True

    ' Capture list of all files in all subfolders
    FilesList = Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Path.Combine(My.Settings.AgencyDataPath, MetroTextBox1.Text), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    ' Add FileCount to Label1
    Label1.Text = FilesList.Count

    ' Initialize ProgressBar
    MetroProgressBar1.Value = 0
    MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = FilesList.Count

    ' Execute DeleteFilesFS in separate thread
    Task.Run(Sub() DeleteFilesFS())
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteFilesFS()

    Dim orderFolder As String
    orderFolder = My.Settings.AgencyDataPath & "\" & MetroTextBox1.Text
    MsgBox(orderFolder)

    For Each Filename As String In FilesList
        Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.Delete(Filename)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Deleting: " & orderFolder)

        UpdateProgress()
    Next

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() Button1.Enabled = True)
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If

    If Label1.Text = 0 Then
        Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.Delete(orderFolder, True)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Finished Deleting: " & orderFolder)
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub DeleteFiles()

    For Each Filename As String In FilesList
        Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.Delete(Filename)

        UpdateProgress()
    Next

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() Button1.Enabled = True)
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgress()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() UpdateProgress())
    Else
        MetroProgressBar1.Value += 1
        MetroProgressBar1.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim orderFolder As String
    orderFolder = My.Settings.AgencyDataPath & "\" & MetroTextBox1.Text
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Started Deleting: " & orderFolder)

    ' Capture list of all files in all subfolders
    FilesList = Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Path.Combine(My.Settings.AgencyDataPath, MetroTextBox1.Text), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    ' Add FileCount to Label1
    Label1.Text = FilesList.Count

    ' Initialize ProgressBar
    MetroProgressBar1.Value = 0
    MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = FilesList.Count

    ' Execute DeleteFiles in separate thread
    Task.Run(Sub() DeleteFiles())
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim orderFolder As String
    orderFolder = My.Settings.AgencyDataPath & "\" & MetroTextBox1.Text


    Label1.Text = FilesList.Count

    If Label1.Text = "0" Then
        Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.Delete(orderFolder, True)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Finished Deleting: " & orderFolder)
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why do you have `ListBox1.Items.Add("-->  Deleting: " & orderFolder)` inside the loop? That's not changing per iteration, and even if it was, I'd think it would complain about not being called from the main UI thread.